# want a link for dell inspiron 15 3000 series 3542 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

i am having a dell inspiron 15 3000 series 3542 laptop with ubuntu. But i have a problem with it so i want to re-install unbuntu in it. Can any one provide a link to download os iso image.

dell inspiron 15 3000 series 3542 laptop i3 processor 64 bit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go on askubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official download page.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

There is no specific packages other than 32/64 architectures.